# Compare three tables for one answers in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been working with MySQL for a while now, and just recently found the need to manage my data better (MOAR DATA!)...

The problem I am having is this:

```
Table1: users
- id

Table2: companies
- companyid
- companyname

Table3: customers
- customerid
- companyid
```

I am trying to query the following.

I have the users ID, I need to use that to get the companyid from customers using the customerid, and return companyname based of the assigned companyid in customers.

It is very possible I am going about this very wrong. I understand that eventually the data is going to get very hard to read by eye as the data starts to grow. My concern is having the ability to associate and disassociate customers from businesses.

If you have any tips, or have a better strategy, or think I should just add this information into the users tables please let me know.

Comment: `select companyname from table2 t2 join table3 t3 on t2.companyid = t3.companyid where t3.customerid = 2`?

Comment: how does the users table connect with table2 or table3?

Comment: Sorry, as I am somewhat new to this particular problem. but are the t2,t3 short reference names to these tables?

Comment: @Dave The user table stores all of the credentials for login. The byproduct being a USERID which I used in companies to reference the USERID to a COMPANYID which references a COMPANYNAME.

Comment: (Aside: we prefer solutions are added in answers, and not as edits to questions. I've added this as an answer just now, please do this yourself in future. Commentary about unhelpful posters also doesn't really belong in questions or answers - they are meant to be relevant for a wide future audience).

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need some understandings on what Normalization is: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878

The database tables are not meant to be "read by eye". I'm pretty sure you are dealing with a very small database now, but imagine in the future you're dealing with thousands of tables with millions of rows, "visual inspection" is not going to work anymore.

A simple join would have given what you need:

```
SELECT t2.companyname 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
WHERE t1.id = t3.customerid 
AND t3.companyid = t2.company id
AND t3.customerid = (some id)  //Depends on what your purpose is, 
                               //this line can also be replaced by
                               //AND t1.id = (some id)
```

In your case, it is possible to combine User table and Customer table into one ONLY if all users are customers too. But it is definitely a NO to have company information in either User or Customer tables.

Comment: thank you first off the for helpful link. I quickly skimmed the overview, and will be reading this later when I have time.

Secondly I was able to use your example above successfully. Thank you.

Comment: As per your latest edit: Users have multiple access levels, some are admins,some are company employees ( the company who needs this database), and some are employees to the companies who need access to this information. I decided to do 3 tables for the sake of not plugging up the user table with data that wasn't required across the board. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `customers.customerid` and `users.id` will be the same value, this should suffice:

```
SELECT companies.companyname
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN companies ON customers.companyid = companies.companyid
WHERE customers.customerid = 5
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7634e/4)**

Schema is on the left, sql is on the right.

**Tables:**

```
users
+--------+
|   ID   |
+--------+
|   1    |
|   2    |
|   3    |
|   4    |
|   5    |
|   6    |
|   7    |
|   8    |
|   9    |
|   10   |
|   11   |
|   12   |
|   13   |
+--------+

companies
+------------------------------------------+
| COMPANYID     COMPANYNAME                |
+------------------------------------------+
| 5             CompAlumpany               |
| 9             Dergy Hergins LLC          |
| 3             Smergy Berg Inc.           |
| 23            Hergin Derz                |
| 7             Comperation corpany        |
| 11            Contagion Engine           |
| 31            AEther Vial                |
| 66            Necropotence               |
| 90            Lord of Atlantis           |
| 65            Snoogins                   |
| 51            Nickty-Schnickty-Schnoine  |
| 58            Take a knee                |
| 59            Coorprate                  |
+------------------------------------------+

customers
+--------------------------+
| CUSTOMERID    COMPANYID  |
+--------------------------+
| 1             5          |
| 2             9          |
| 3             3          |
| 4             23         |
| 5             7          |
| 6             11         |
| 7             31         |
| 8             66         |
| 9             90         |
| 10            65         |
| 11            51         |
| 12            58         |
| 13            59         |
+--------------------------+
```

**Query Returns:**

```
+---------------------+
| COMPANYNAME         |
+---------------------+
| Comperation corpany |
+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

*Posted on behalf of the OP.*

I got the results I was looking for with the following:

```
SELECT t2.companyname FROM companies t2,customers t3 WHERE t3.companyid = t2.companyid AND t3.customerid=?
```

I was unaware I could create references, this will become very useful for me. Thank you!

Comment: Why would you move my results to another post?

Comment: Hi there @jjonesdesign - see my note under your question. As an active editor I tend to move [SOLVED] notes to answers, so they are cleanly separated. It is marked as 'community wiki', so I get no reputation points for doing so.